# git rebase - what's the difference between 'edit' and 'reword'

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

What's the difference between `edit` and `reword` when you do a git rebase?

I'm going through some docs which say this:

```
Replace pick with:
- edit to mark a commit for amending.
- reword to change the log message.
```

Comment: I just typed the exact title of this question into Google! +1 for useful title.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

- "reword" allows you to change **ONLY the commit message, NOT the commit contents**
- "edit" allows you to change **BOTH commit contents AND commit message** (the mechanism by which git allows you to edit the commit contents is by "pausing" the rebase; so you can amend the commit)

**reference** :
The [git-rebase documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) says this:

- *edit* : By replacing the command "pick" with the command "edit", you can tell git rebase to stop after applying that commit, so that you can edit the files and/or the commit message, amend the commit, and continue rebasing.
- *reword* : If you just want to edit the commit message for a commit, replace the command "pick" with the command "reword".

Comment: Does the name of original committer changes if `reword` is used?

Answer (score 25):

`edit` will pause the rebase entirely, allowing you to change files in the commit and/or the commit message.

`reword` will simply open an editor to let you change the commit message only.